# Customize Header Background Transparent

Tags: css, wordpress

Is there a way to make the header of wordpress site transparent and make the slider be seen through it?

this is the wordpress site I'm trying to customize the header.

http://xusom2.mymediapaldesign.com/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't catch the full implications of the question (and what you mean by 'slider'), but the easiest answer that comes to mind is, use CSS.

```
header{background:none;}
```

or

```
header {opacity:0.5;} /*any number between 0 and 1*/
```

if you wanna change the opacity of the background, something like this:

```
header {background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);} /*where 0.9 is the opacity and the rest is the color in RGB*/
```

too easy?